# Can't make Stimulus JS data-action in collection_select Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, collection-select, stimulusjs, form-with

I'm new to Stimulus JS. I'm a little stuck trying to make a simple event fire using `collection_select` in a form (created with rails g scaffold).

Here's my `dropdown-controller.js` (stimulus) file:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["target"];

  handleChange() {
    console.log('works!')
  }
}
```

Here's my `_forms.html.erb` file:

```
<%= form_with(model: stock_order, local: true) do |form| %>
  ...

  <section data-controller="dropdown">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :company_id %>
      <%= form.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, data: {action: "change->dropdown#handleChange"} %>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've tried many things:

`<%= form.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, data: {action: "change->dropdown#handleChange"} %>`

`<%= form.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, {data: {action: "change->dropdown#handleChange"}} %>`

`<%= form.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, data: {action: "dropdown#handleChange"} %>`
...etc

I can only get to fire the `console.log('works!)` if I use html select tags instead of rails' `collection_select`. The event fires if I create a test button or if I use `form.check_box` instead.

Any ideas? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that according to Stimulus [naming conventions](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions#naming-conventions), you should not name your callback function `handleChange`. Instead find something more related to what you want to happen when the select changes.

Answer (score 2):

The `data-` are html attributes, so you miss one parameter in `form.collection_select` call

```
<%= form.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, nil, data: {action: "change->dropdown#handleChange"} %>
```

See [the method description](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select)

Comment: How do you access the `:id` in the Stimulus controller?